# Does using shared dataset result in single DB call

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have created a shared dataset and using it in multiple times in report with different filters to address business requirements. I would like to know whether this is still a single DB execution call.

I have looked at profiler trace when the report gets executed but not able to figure out much from it.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the profiler and showed the underlying stored procedure being executed multiple times. This confirms that the dataset data is not shared